# Centering a background image in the middle of a page

Tags: html, css

not sure why I can't get this to work.  All I am trying to do is: 1) put a background that is 100% of the screen but with a minimum size of 784px, and then I want to center another image in the middle of the page.

JsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/lep128/TbSfB/

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="container"></div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif !important;
  background-image: url('https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS-ETyIzR8JeSwXRYpHDijfM4g5vIR8RcpzMmSE3AvCdnHPmrje');
  background-size: 100%;
  min-height: 784px;
}
.container {
    background: transparent url('https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSRfXpcWInB-fB96WuQLAR2JPlhAwyssVbVetadWWXXYgh5ZV22yQ') center center no-repeat;
    width: 455px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    clear: both;
    height: 525px;
}​
```

AS you can see the Earth stays at the top of the page rather than going to the center.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

your .container object middle will be height:784px try this.

Comment: But what if the user is viewing it in a monitor that is larger than 784px?  In this case the image would no longer be centered.

Comment: If that is the case even your width, height & min-height of mentioning hardcoded px value will fail with respective to the display sizes ... then go for % everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif !important;
      background-image: url('https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS-ETyIzR8JeSwXRYpHDijfM4g5vIR8RcpzMmSE3AvCdnHPmrje');
      background-size: 100%;
      height: 100%;
   }

.container {
    background: transparent url('https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSRfXpcWInB-fB96WuQLAR2JPlhAwyssVbVetadWWXXYgh5ZV22yQ') 50% 50% no-repeat;
    width: 455px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 525px;
}​
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddler Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TbSfB/19/)

```
.body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif !important;
  background-image: url('https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS-ETyIzR8JeSwXRYpHDijfM4g5vIR8RcpzMmSE3AvCdnHPmrje');
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  background: transparent url('https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSRfXpcWInB-fB96WuQLAR2JPlhAwyssVbVetadWWXXYgh5ZV22yQ') center no-repeat;
  width: 455px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 784px;
}​
```